# Reverse an array in JavaScript without mutating the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

*[Array.prototype.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reverse)* reverses the contents of an array in place (with mutation)...

Is there a similarly simple strategy for reversing an array without altering the contents of the original array (without mutation)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an independent copy of a reversed array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23666679/1048572)

Comment: Here's a benchmark comparing the different options: http://jsben.ch/HZ7Zp

Answer (score 694, accepted):

You can use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make a copy then [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) it

```
var newarray = array.slice().reverse();
```

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var newarray = array.slice().reverse();

console.log('a', array);
console.log('na', newarray);
```

Comment: Can you please explaing slice() with no parameters?

Comment: @Alex [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - `If begin is omitted, slice begins from index 0.` - so it is the same as `array.slice(0)`

Comment: I think @Alex meant 'explain it in your answer'...regardless...Brilliant solution.  Thanks!

Comment: I would NOT recommend to use this approach, because it's very misleading practice. It’s very confusing when you use slice() and you actually not slicing anything.

If you need immutable reverse, just create fresh new copy:

***const newArray = [...array].reverse()***

Comment: Can we all just take a moment to identify how much further JavaScript needs to grow?  This is the best we've got?  Cmon JavaScript!  grow up a little.

Comment: @OlegMatei Slicing the whole array is still slicing. It's not confusing if you understand what `Array#slice` does. There's no reason spread syntax should be any less confusing.

Comment: @OlegMatei I understand your point about misleading code. However, `slice()` still seems to be the fastest option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52929821/1480587

Comment: In 2024, this is still the fastest way of doing it( and probably the most supported), even compared with `Array.prototype.toReversed()`

Answer (score 221):

In ES6:

```
const newArray = [...array].reverse()
```

Comment: How does the performance of this compare with that of the accepted answer? Are they the same?

Comment: I'm consistently getting `.slice` as significantly faster.

Comment: @JamesCoyle It's probably browser and OS dependent, but `slice` is likely to be faster b/c `[...]` is a generic iterable-to-array so cannot make as many assumptions. As well, it's likely that `slice` is better optimized b/c it's been around a long time.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52929821/1480587 about benchmarks of different versions for dupicating an array.

Answer (score 21):

```js
const originalArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

const newArray = Array.from(originalArray).reverse();

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: I like this because the intent is more explicit. Its not obvious that `slice()` creates a duplicate array.

Comment: You can read it as *"Create a new array from `originalArray` then reverse it"*

Answer (score 17):

Another ES6 variant:

We can also use `.reduceRight()` to create a reversed array without actually reversing it.

```js
let A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

let B = A.reduceRight((a, c) => (a.push(c), a), []);

console.log(B);
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Comma Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: `reduceRight` is slow af

Comment: @DragosRizescu Can you share some sample test results?

Comment: Here is a repo that you can play with: (not the best example, but had this argument with someone a while ago in a React context, thus I've put it together): https://github.com/rizedr/reduce-vs-reduceRight

Comment: `(a, c) => a.concat([c])` feels more idiomatic than `(a, c) => (a.push(c), a)`

Comment: @DragosRizescu it actually looks like this is the fastest of the 3 top answers. https://jsperf.com/reverse-vs-slice-reverse/3

Comment: @KyleLin It's a much slower though. The really idiomatic solution would be not to use a concise arrow function but `(a, c) => { a.push(c); return a; }`

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes, most of the time. But if `c` is an array, then the resulting behavior will be different than what the OP intended.

Comment: That Comma operator is kind of crazy cool and taught me something and the `reduceRight` is definitely a strong part of functional programming - but it makes the code really confusing to read. Performant or not, I'd rather the [@Ragu's explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71475972/327074) `const B = Array.from(A).reverse()` than the three or four levels of understanding it takes for your `reduceRight`.

Comment: In 2024 this is by far the slowest version. A new native Array.prototype.toReversed() is available but is actually quite slower than the other alternatives (spread, slice, arrayFrom)

Answer (score 11):

#### ES2023 Array Method [toReversed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toReversed)

The `toReversed()` method transposes the elements of the calling array object in reverse order and returns a new array.

```
const items = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(items); // [1, 2, 3]

const reversedItems = items.toReversed();
console.log(reversedItems); // [3, 2, 1]
console.log(items); // [1, 2, 3]
```

**Browser compatibility**

[image]

Comment: 2024: For some reason this is significantly slower (~20% slower) than `items.slice().reverse()`, `[...items].reverse()` or `Array.from(items).reverse()`. The slice version being consistently the fastest by a small margin, and probably the most widely supported. At least on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways of reversing an array without modifying. Two of them are

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Using slice
var reverseArray1 = array.slice().reverse(); // Fastest

// Using spread operator
var reverseArray2 = [...array].reverse();

// Using for loop 
var reverseArray3 = []; 
for(var i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  reverseArray.push(array[i]);
}
```

Performance test http://jsben.ch/guftu

Comment: is there any performance difference between `array.splice()` as you wrote and the `slice()` method?

Comment: It should be `slice()` and not `splice()`.  The latter returns an empty array.

Answer (score 7):

Try this recursive solution:

```
const reverse = ([head, ...tail]) => 
    tail.length === 0
        ? [head]                       // Base case -- cannot reverse a single element.
        : [...reverse(tail), head]     // Recursive case

reverse([1]);               // [1]
reverse([1,2,3]);           // [3,2,1]
reverse('hello').join('');  // 'olleh' -- Strings too!
```

Comment: This looks like it would break for empty arrays.

Answer (score 6):

An ES6 alternative using `.reduce()` and spreading.

```
const foo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const bar = foo.reduce((acc, b) => ([b, ...acc]), []);
```

Basically what it does is create a new array with the next element in foo, and spreading the accumulated array for each iteration after b.

```
[]
[1] => [1]
[2, ...[1]] => [2, 1]
[3, ...[2, 1]] => [3, 2, 1]
[4, ...[3, 2, 1]] => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Alternatively `.reduceRight()` as mentioned above here, but without the `.push()` mutation.

```
const baz = foo.reduceRight((acc, b) => ([...acc, b]), []);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a new [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy), which adds a `toReversed` method to `Array` that returns a copy of the array and doesn't modify the original.

Example from the proposal:

```js
const sequence = [1, 2, 3];
sequence.toReversed(); // => [3, 2, 1]
sequence; // => [1, 2, 3]
```

As it's currently in stage 3, it will likely be implemented in browser engines soon, but in the meantime a polyfill is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.toreversed) or in [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#change-array-by-copy).

Answer (score 2):

```
const arrayCopy = Object.assign([], array).reverse()
```

This solution:

-Successfully copies the array

-Doesn't mutate the original array

-Looks like it's doing what it is doing

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2023:**

**Array.prototype.toReversed()** is the new **ES2023** method for returning a reversed array, *without* modifying the original one.

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(items); // [1, 2, 3]
    
const reversedItems = items.toReversed();
console.log('reversedItems', reversedItems); // [3, 2, 1]
console.log('items', items); // [1, 2, 3]
```

It's also possible to use it on **sparse arrays**:
`console.log([1, , 3].toReversed()); // [3, undefined, 1]`
and on **non-array objects**

Answer (score 1):

Reversing in place with variable swap just for demonstrative purposes (but you need a copy if you don't want to mutate)

```
const myArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const copy = [...myArr];
for (let i = 0; i < (copy.length - 1) / 2; i++) {  
    const lastIndex = copy.length - 1 - i; 
    [copy[i], copy[lastIndex]] = [copy[lastIndex], copy[i]] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jumping into 2022, and here's the most efficient solution today (highest-performing, and no extra memory usage).

---

For any `ArrayLike` type, the fastest way to reverse is logically, by wrapping it into a reversed iterable:

```
function reverse<T>(input: ArrayLike<T>): Iterable<T> {
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
            let i = input.length;
            return {
                next(): IteratorResult<T> {
                    return i
                        ? {value: input[--i], done: false}
                        : {value: undefined, done: true};
                },
            };
        },
    };
}
```

This way you can reverse-iterate through any `Array`, `string` or `Buffer`, without any extra copy or processing for the reversed data:

```
for(const a of reverse([1, 2, 3])) {
    console.log(a); //=> 3 2 1
}
```

It is the fastest approach, because you do not copy the data, and do no processing at all, you just reverse it logically.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a similarly simple strategy for reversing an array without altering the contents of the original array (without mutation) ?*

Yes, there is a way to achieve this by using `to[Operation]` that return a new collection with the operation applied (This is currently at stage 3, will be available soon).

Implementation will be like **:**

```
const arr = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

const reversedArr = arr.toReverse();

console.log(arr); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

console.log(reversedArr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: arr.toReverse is not a function` `toReverse` is not a thing in JavaScript.

Comment: @Cerbrus not a thing *yet* - it's still [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy) which is in the last stage before being finalised. Polyfills are available to preview the functionality: [for example here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#change-array-by-copy).

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but it works

```js
Array.prototype.myNonMutableReverse = function () {
  const reversedArr = [];
  for (let i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) reversedArr.push(this[i]);
  return reversedArr;
};

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const b = a.myNonMutableReverse();
console.log("a",a);
console.log("////////")
console.log("b",b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an older version of Node (<20), where `.reverse()` and `.toReversed()` are not available, here's the shortest one-liner alternative I could come up with:

`console.log([1,2,3].map((_, i, a) => a[a.length - 1 - i])); // [3,2,1]`

```
/** Reverses an array without mutating the original. */
export function revArr<T>(arr: T[]): T[] {
  return arr.map((_, i, a) => a[a.length - 1 - i]);
}
```

Answer (score -9):

es6:

```
const reverseArr = [1,2,3,4].sort(()=>1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Radion! When leaving an answer it's typically a good idea to explain why your answer works and why you came to this conclusion, this helps newer users with understanding the interactions and languages you have specified.

Comment: In Radion's defense :P
that `1` at the end could have been anything greater than zero, because that's how `Array.prototype.sort` callback (or so called `compare function`)  works. Basically you always compare 2 numbers and in this case the comparison returns always positive so it says always move to the second number in front of the first one :)
this is very explanatory: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function

Comment: `sort()` mutates the array (i.e., sorts it in place), which is what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: This answer is wrong in several ways.  (1) it mutates the array, as @ClintHarris points out, so it's no better than .reverse().  (2) your comparator is illegal-- when you return 1 for a,b, you must return a negative number for b,a.  If your answer reverses the array on some implementations, it's entirely by luck.

Comment: Please test code when submitting it. At the very least it should do the required task, even if it does mutate the array. This just doesn't work as intended (it doesn't change the array at all) ([demo](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10j2lDHSMdYxyRWrzi/qERDQ9PWzlBT8/9/AA)) and is easily corrected with the addition of a single character.