# How to do a loop in JSON from the last record JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, loops

I have a JSON like this:

```
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];
```

How can I get the value of a specific attribute of each record (intStageNum for example) but I have to do it backwards. I have to start the loop from the last record which is

```
{ "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to start the loop from the last record?

Comment: I have some lines of code but in order for that to work, the loop should start from the last record.

Comment: copy the data, and reverse the copy, and then loop over as per usual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below loop:

```js
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];

for (var i=(arrStages.length-1); i>=0; i--){
  console.log(arrStages[i]['intStageNum']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=arrStages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(arrStages[i].intStageNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have been giving you an iterative approach: I think it is better to use the `forEach` or `map` approach, as it makes the code easier to read.

Some solutions are simply writing `arrStages["intStageNum"]` within the for loop. This is not extensible if you want to find some other attribute.

Instead, we define a function `findElement` that takes two arguments `array` and `element`. These arguments should be self explanatory.

Lastly, we do not want to mutate the array so we should not call `array.reverse`. Instead, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610523/reverse-array-in-javascript-without-mutating-original-array) tells us to use `array.slice.reverse` instead.

```js
    var arrStages = [                 
        { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
        { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
        { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
        { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
        { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
        { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 }
    ];
    
    
    function findElement(array, attr) {
     array.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element[attr]);
      });
    }
    
    findElement(arrStages.slice().reverse(), "intStageNum");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using "reduceRight"?

```
arrStages.reduceRight(function(nothing, record){
     yourCheckFunction(record);
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways.

1) the usual way. use i-- loop coming back from arrStages.length-1 to arrStage[0]

2) do while loop and pop element as you go. (Assuming you need to free up the memory by deleting elements from the end of the array.

Since both are going through n object, so it's O(n). You really don't get any benefit on performance here.  But it's just an alternative.

I personally don't like .reverse much because after you reverse it, you still need to go through the for loop again. It's looping twice.. but :p I don't think that matters.

```js
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];

while (arrStages.length > 0) {
  poped = arrStages.pop();
  console.log(poped.intStageNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first reverse the array with reverse() method and then start iterating it with foreach loop. as **reverse() is mutating array** so you can you try something like following

```
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];
arrStages.reverse();
arrStages.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

or you can start your loop with last index to first like this

`for(var i=arrStages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

and as you need to iterate all the array so for O(n) complexity if you are having much larger arrays then use for loop from end to start.