# Why does pushing to one array affect another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following code snippet:

```js
var arr1 = "john".split('');
console.log(arr1); // [ 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n' ]
var arr2 = arr1.reverse();
console.log(arr1); // [ 'n', 'h', 'o', 'j' ]
var arr3 = "jones".split('');
arr2.push(arr3);
console.log(arr1); // [ 'n', 'h', 'o', 'j', [ 'j', 'o', 'n', 'e', 's' ] ]
```

In the last `console.log`, why does pushing to `arr2` affect `arr1`? Why does `arr1` change when it's not modified, only `arr2` is modified?

Comment: *"In the last console.log, why does pushing to arr2 affect arr3?"* - It doesn't. The last log is logging `arr1`, not `arr3`.

Comment: @nnnnnn An editing mistake on my part, fixed

Answer (score 2):

The `reverse()` method in JavaScript [*mutates* the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse?v=control). This means that it changes the data in place—in the `arr1` variable—and then returns a reference to that array. So `arr2` is just a reference to `arr1`, rather than a new set of data.

If you want completely new data, you can do as they say in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610523/reverse-array-in-javascript-without-mutating-original-array):

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice().reverse();
```

That will `slice` a new set of data and then reverse it, hence returning a new array instead of a reference to the first array.

Example:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var notmutated = array.slice();
console.log('not mutated:', notmutated);

var mutated = array.reverse();
console.log('mutated: ', array);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two modifications to `arr1` taking place on your code.

> var arr2 = arr1.reverse();

The function [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses an array *in place*. This means that `arr1` will be reversed itself.

Also, when assigning objects, you are only passing a reference to them, so `arr2` is actually `arr1` (reversed) after this line.

> arr2.push(arr3);

Because you assigned `arr2` as a reference to `arr1`, in this line you are actually modifying `arr1`, being equivalent to writing `arr1.push(arr3)`.

To create a new object from an array, you can use the function [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example), since this method *returns a copy* of an array.

```js
var arr1 = "john".split('');  
console.log(arr1); // [ 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n' ]
var arr2 = arr1.slice().reverse(); 
console.log(arr1); // [ 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n' ]
var arr3 = "jones".split(''); 
arr2.push(arr3);
console.log(arr1);  // [ 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr1 = "john".split('');  
console.log(arr1); // [ 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n' ]
var arr2 = arr1.slice().reverse(); 
console.log(arr2); // [ 'n', 'h', 'o', 'j' ]
var arr3 = "jones".split(''); 
arr2.push(arr3);
console.log(arr1);  // [ 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n' ]
console.log(arr2);  // [ 'n', 'h', 'o', 'j', ['j','o','n','e','s'] ]
```

1. split() function return a new array.
2. reverse() function does not return a new array. So, arr1 is arr2.
3. push() function does not return a new array. So, arr1 and arr2 have added the arr3 as the last element.

Use slice() function to make a copy of your array.

References:

[split function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

[reverse function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/reverse-method-javascript)

[push function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)