# How javascript language is working

Tags: javascript

i am a new learner on javascript language but i have worked before with other programming language such c#

while i was doing a simple operation on javascript, i was astonished about the results makes me wonder how javascript works and why it is different like that

Example
i had an array of ['a','b'] , i want to reverse it and check is it the same or not

> var char = ['a','b'];
>
> var char_reversed = char.reverse();

normally , char should = ['a','b']  and char_revered should = ['b','a']

but i find that char = char_reversed = ['b','a']

Comment: [`reverse()` works in-place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), what's so hard to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript some methods don't create new reference of your data. It's change your your data within the own memory. For example,

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.reverse();
console.log (a); // a looks like [3, 2, 1]

a.pop();
console.log (a); // a looks like [3, 2] data changes within the memory. 

console.log (a.slice(0, 1)); // output looks like [3]

console.log (a); // a looks like [3, 2]
```

In slice method that create new memory of your data and modified your new data. So your old data don't change or modified.

Comment: i think you mean the output on using slice looks like [3], but thanks for the explanation it is a great help

Comment: Ohh sorry I don't saw it. I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

The `reverse` function works in place, therefore the original array is modified.

If you do not want to modify the original list, you can refer to the following post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30610528/759762

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works is that `char.reverse()` operates on the array `char`. It does not perform the operation and returns a copy of the array, but changes the array itself. The operation `var char_reversed = char.reverse()` actually is:

```
char.reverse() // ['b','a']
char_reversed = char
```

That is why `char = char_reversed = ['b','a']`

Comment: is this methodology of operating on the variable itself not creating a copy, exist on other methods or is it just the arrays which perform this way

Answer (score 0):

`.reverse()` modifies original array.

You can call `.slice()` first to create a copy of the original array if you are expecting a new array where the elements are literal strings.

```js
var char = ['a','b'];

var char_reversed = char.slice(0).reverse();

console.log(char, char_reversed);
```