# How to get a reversed ReadonlyArray?

Tags: typescript

If I have a `ReadonlyArray<T>` and I want to obtain another `ReadonlyArray<T>` with the same items but in reverse order, what's the easiest way to achieve that?

For example:

```
const scoresInAscendingOrder: ReadonlyArray<number> = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9];
const scoresInDescendingOrder: ReadonlyArray<number> =  ???;
```

I can't use `scoresInAscendingOrder.reverse()` because `ReadonlyArray` does not support that method (and rightly so since it would modify `scoresInAscendingOrder`).

Comment: See [Reverse array in Javascript without mutating original array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30610523/1715579) -- that question not about typescript but almost every answer there will also work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `slice` and reverse the result of that:

```
const scoresInAscendingOrder: ReadonlyArray<number> = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9];
const scoresInDescendingOrder: ReadonlyArray<number> = scoresInAscendingOrder.slice(0).reverse()
```

Or you can use the newer spread syntax:

```
const scoresInDescendingOrder: ReadonlyArray<number> = [...scoresInAscendingOrder].reverse()
```

Comment: Or spread the original array? `[...scoresInAscendingOrder].reverse()`